# Not outputting the calculation, just 0

Tags: c++

I have my code here and it runs, however, when I try to output the percentage it just outputs 0, I've spent a long time trying to figure out what I'm missing and I'm clueless. Basically I'm trying to output the percent of votes for each candidate out of total votes. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my output;
[Output display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW3wl.png) Also, im aware that the winner loops through every user until it reaches the end for some reason, still trying to work out the kinks.

Here is my code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;

class candidatesElection
{
public:

    string last;
    float votePercent;
    void winnerOfElection();
    void outputDis();
    int total = 0;
};

int main()
{

    string lastName[5];
    int amountOfVotes[5];
    double percentTotal[5];
    int total = 0;
    int winnerNo = 0;
    int winningCandidate;
    string winningName;


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the last name of the Candidate: " << endl;
        cin >> lastName[i];
        cout << endl;

        cout << "Enter the votes received by the Candidate: " << endl;
        cin >> amountOfVotes[i];


        total += amountOfVotes[i];
        cout << "Total number of votes is: " << total << endl;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (amountOfVotes[i] > amountOfVotes[winnerNo]) winnerNo = i;
        amountOfVotes[i] = amountOfVotes[winnerNo];
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        percentTotal[i] = (amountOfVotes[i] / total) * 100.0; // need to make it floating point
    }

    void outputDis();
    {
        cout << endl << left << setw(25) << "Candidate" << right << setw(25) << "Votes Received" << setw(25) << "% of Total Votes" << endl;


        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            cout << endl << left << setw(25) << lastName[i] << right << setw(25) << amountOfVotes[i] << setw(25) << percentTotal[i] << endl;
        cout << endl << left << setw(25) << "Total" << right << setw(25) << total << endl;


        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {

            int winHigh = amountOfVotes[0];
            string win = lastName[0];
            if (amountOfVotes[i] > winHigh)
            {
                winHigh = amountOfVotes[i];
                win = lastName[i];
            }
            cout << "The Winner of the Election is " << win << endl;

        }
    }

        system("pause");



};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The coefficient `amountOfVotes[i] / total` in `(amountOfVotes[i] / total) * 100.0` is evalated in *integer arithmetic*: i.e. any fraction is discarded.

So you end up with `0 * 100` for all cases where `amountOfVotes[i]` is less than `total`.

The solution is to rearrange the formula to `100 * amountOfVotes[i] / total;`, or, even better `100.0 * amountOfVotes[i] / total;` which will force evaluation in double precision floating point - you are in danger of overflowing an `int` which, on some systems, can have an upper limit as low as 32767.

That's not immediately obvious even when using a line-by-line debugger. But do use that debugger to work out the other "kinks".

Comment: Thank you this makes more sense! However when I changed it, for some reason it outputs some of the values as the same. ie. I entered the scores 34, 56, 78, 96, 45 and it outputs 34, 56, 78, 96, 96?

Comment: That, I think, is because you reassign `int winHigh = amountOfVotes[0];` in the *body* of the final `for` loop. Note that your output is monotonically increasing, and the deviation happens when you input score decreases.

Comment: Ignore me I just realized my code is outputting the "candidate score" wrong! It's repeating some values for some reason? Your solution worked for the percentage, thanks!

Comment: thanks! If I remove it from the body where do you think it should be placed instead? Running a few checks now. (Will also mark you best answer when it lets me)

Comment: Immediately before the `for` loop starts.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much :)